# Emacs how remove all text except "some_text"?

Tags: replace, emacs

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.

Suppose I have text:

```
    MyActivity.java:124:       RestClient().getAuth("api/method1" + Integer.toString(id) + ".json")
MyActivity2.java:224    RestClient().getAuth("api/method2" + Integer.toString(id) + ".json")
MyActivity2.java:224:      RestClient().getAuth("api/method2" + Integer.toString(id) + ".json")
MyFragment.java:684:    RestClient().getAuth("api/method2" + Integer.toString(id) + ".json")
MyActivity2.java:224:        RestClient().getAuth("api/method1" + Float.toString(id) + ".xml")
Fragment.java:234:    RestClient().getAuth("api/method1" + Integer.toString(id) + ".json")
MyActivity2.java:224:        RestClient().getAuth("api/method4" + Float.toString(id) + ".xml")
```

How I can remove all text except "api/xxx". So result must be:

`"api/method1"
"api/method2"
"api/method2"
"api/method2"
"api/method1"
"api/method1"
"api/method4"`

I want to use built-in capabilities of Emacs (without write custom elisp script or Emacs macros).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were happy for the results to be output in a separate buffer, you could use `occur` like so:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> `"api/.+?"` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Select the lines you want to modify and run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`replace-regexp`.  Use `.*\("api/.+?"\).*` for the replace regexp and for the replacement use `\1`.

This regex says:

- `.*` - match any number of any character
- `\(...\)` - saving the bit between the parens
- `"api/.+?"` - a literal `"api/` followed by anything up to and including the next `"`.
- `.*` - followed by any number of any character

And replace it with `\1`, which is whatever text was in the first (and only) set of `\(\)` above.

The output is the expected:

```
"api/method1"
"api/method2"
"api/method2"
"api/method2"
"api/method1"
"api/method1"
"api/method4"
```